# issue with OAuth2 oltu

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, jax-rs, facebook-oauth

I am working on securing our REST api's with OAuth2.
The code i have written is not complete code, currently i am just testing it..

Using below code i am making a token request.

```
public class OauthClientmine {  
public static void main (String args[]) throws OAuthSystemException, IOException, OAuthProblemException{
    getToken();
}   
public static void getToken() throws OAuthSystemException, IOException, OAuthProblemException{
    OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
            .tokenLocation("http://localhost:8080/xina/webapi/token")
            .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .setClientId("xina_client")
            .setClientSecret("xinaisawesome")
            .setCode("xyxyxy")
            .setUsername("john")
            .setRedirectURI("http://localhost:8080/xina/webapi/token")
            .setPassword("password")
            .buildQueryMessage();       
    OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());       
    OAuthAccessTokenResponse oauthResponse = oAuthClient.accessToken(request);      
    final OAuthAccessTokenResponse oAuthResponse = oAuthClient.accessToken(request);        
    System.out.println(oauthResponse.getAccessToken());
    System.out.println(oauthResponse.getExpiresIn());       
    System.out.println( request.getLocationUri());  
}}
```

Once token request is received i am validating client details and then i will send authorized token using below code.

```
@Path("/token")
public class AuthorizeClient {  
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getToken(@Context HttpServletRequest  tokenRequest) throws OAuthSystemException, OAuthProblemException{     
    //OAuthTokenRequest oauthRequest = new OAuthTokenRequest(tokenRequest);
    System.out.println(     request.getClass());        
    OAuthIssuer oauthIssuerImpl = new OAuthIssuerImpl(new MD5Generator());      
    OAuthResponse response = OAuthASResponse
            .tokenResponse(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)
            .setAccessToken(oauthIssuerImpl.accessToken())
            .setExpiresIn("3600")
            .buildJSONMessage();        
    return Response.status(response.getResponseStatus())
            .entity(response.getBody())
            .build();
}}
```

But the issue i am facing is my request  ***tokenRequest*** 
is null, i am not sure how can i intercept client details before sending token